# How to read part of file to std::list buffer?

Tags: c++, list, fstream

With `std::vector` I used this:

```
list_buffer_bytes.resize(BUFFER_SIZE_8_MB);
file_source.read(&vector_buffer_bytes[0], BUFFER_SIZE_8_MB * sizeof(char));
```

But I can't do that if I change type from std::vector to std::list

Comment: If `BUFFER_SIZE_8_MB` is what is seems to be, creating an `std::list` that holds 8 megabytes of individual bytes is going to be a horror show. In general, when you read from a file you should read into a contiguous data area. `std::list` is not contiguous, and trying to jam bytes into a list will involve a huge amount of overhead (probably 16 bytes for each data byte) and a great deal of heap thrashing. Unless there's a really compelling reason for such an inefficient use of memory, don't do this.

Comment: Aside: `sizeof(char)` is *by definition* 1

Comment: @PeteBecker, "contiguous data area" is just an array? What is this? And what best size of buffer to read from disk?

Comment: "The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array." [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Yes, an array. Beyond that, it highly depends on the details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: So if I want to read buffer byte by byte, std::vector will be the best option?

Comment: A contiguous buffer (array) allows you to use `std::istream::read` to read in a block of data.  The input system will read one datum into memory, increment a pointer and read the next datum into memory.  This process can be delegated to hardware devices (such as DMA controllers and UARTs).  This process is not efficiently implemented by hardware with linked lists.  With linked list: 1) allocate node, 2) read datum into node, 3) link new node to list.

Answer (score 0):

I would to it like this:

```
std::list<uchar> lst;

std::ifstream stream("somefile.txt");

for(int i=0;i<8192;i++)
{
   uchar a=0;
   stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a),sizeof(uchar));
   lst.push_back(a);
}
```

The issue with this approach come from the fact that you cannot make a cast later because the bytes in a linked list (no matter if it is single, double or else chained) are not contiguous in memory.
So if you later want to recast to another type you can do that that way:

```
reinterpret_cast<output_type*>(std::vector<uchar>(lst.begin(),lst.end()).data());
```

Hope it help you.